# How to trade items in Multiplayer

Tags: starbound

this is kind of an easy question, but I can't find the answer to this anywhere.
When I play multiplayer with a friend, how can we trade Items? (For example something basic like the pick axe)...?

Comment: It's okay.  It is a rather simple question, but it's also entirely appropriate.  I know that there's a specific key that you can press to drop an item, and if you do that, your friend can pick it up off the ground.  I want to say "Q', but I can't remember offhand.

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it workss!! Thank you! Make it an answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's okay to ask simple questions, especially since the game doesn't really tell you this upfront.

You can drop a held item by pressing 'Q'.  Anybody who's nearby can then pick it up.

Comment: Any way to only drop ONE item of one sort? For example if I have 10 Wooden Planks and only want to drop one...?

Comment: I believe you can shift-click items to only take a certain amount of them, or right-shift-click, or ctrl-click, some special click combined with holding either shift or ctrl.  sorry I couldn't be more specific.

Comment: Right clicking a stack will take half of the stack.